# Como evitar que entren a otra pagina sin estar logueados en Django

Tags: html, django

He visto otros post pero ninguno resuelve mi duda, estoy iniciando en Django y me gustaría saber como se hace eso. Pero lo que siempre veo, es que lo hacen ligado al sistema de usuarios de Django, pero como lo hago desde un Form que consulta desde SQL Server u cualquier otro SQL?

Es decir, el usuario y password lo consulto desde una consulta SQL, si existe, que le de acceso a las demás rutas de mi pagina.

Algún tutorial? Recomendación? Pagina?

Comment: Para evitar que un usuario acceda a una url o pagina sin estar loggeado, puedes utilisar el decorador `login_required`, para mas info visita la documentacion: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: También échale un vistaso al `LoginRequiredMixin`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar varias formas: LoginRequiredMixin

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

Desde el request también puedes:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # Do something for authenticated users.
    ...
else:
    # Do something for anonymous users.
    ...
```

Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/